# Exchange message JavaFX gui to C++ application on the same machine

Tags: java, c++, javafx

i would like to know what kind of solution i have to communication between my gui in JavaFX and to another program written in C++.  Both programs are running on the same machine.  Data to be exchanged are not big.  Both running on windows.

Comment: I don't know what's supported by JavaFX, but you have named pipes, message queues, sockets, and lots of other alternatives.

Comment: Could use CORBA or something like ApacheMQ.

Comment: Ok I will use sockets from Java, i just think that it was not so appropriate as it will be on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you Apache Thrift. I'm actually using it for the purpose you described here. It works between a lot of platforms like Java, Ruby, C++, C#, Pascal, Python etc. It's very easy to use.

Check this [Apache thrift homepage](http://thrift.apache.org/).

And here is a tutorial with some sample sources:

[Tutorial 1](http://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/apache-thrift-quickstart-tutorial/)

This tutorial shows the interconnection with C#:

[Java and C# interconnection](http://1b1t.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/thriftpart-six-implementing-c-client/)

And here are some sample sourcecodes:

[Sample sources](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8d3e091cc94025b2&resid=8D3E091CC94025B2!616&id=8D3E091CC94025B2!616)

Comment: if you had any additional questions just ask. :)

Comment: Hi, I've moved my tutorial to this location: [thrift tutorial](http://www.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/)